# Multi-threading testing of Semaphore based business logic in C# / MSTEST

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, mstest

In my C# / Net Core project, I have a method like

```
 var MySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

 public async Task<RetrievalStatusReply> InitializeUpdate()
        {

            // This instruction lets routine quit if lock is taken by other thread
            if (!MySemaphore.Wait(0))
            {
                // if can not enter the lock
                 return;
            }

            try
            {
                // business logic
            }
            finally
            {
                MySemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
```

and would like to test its behaviour using some kind of multi-threading setup or test utility library in an MsTest, for example, similar to Java's [Concurrentunit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit).

How I could write such a test for C# / Net Core ?

Comment: Why use semaphores in the first place? You're already using tasks and `async/await` so your code shouldn't have to lock or wait. Are you trying to throttle that method? Or lazily initialize just once?

Comment: As for how to test asynchronous code, you're already using tasks. You can use `Task.Run` to run something on a new thread **but** .NET and the TPL have higher-level libraries than Java, like Channels, Dataflow, PLINQ etc. In this case though, it looks like you want Lazy<T>

Comment: If you want to execute requests with a limited DOP, or one at a time, you can use DataFlow blocks or Channels with a single reader task. With both namespaces, you can use input/output buffering. With channels you can specify what happens if the buffer is full, eg await, discard first, discard last

Comment: You could also use ReactiveX to throttle requests. In this case though I suspect you could use a Channel with a single-slot buffer and DropNewest behavior

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a perfectly normal pattern: `async/await` does let methods be re-entrant *on a single thread* (execution can be suspended at multiple `await` statements at the same time, on a single thread), so this is something you need to be careful about, and using locks (but not synchronously blocking on them) is a normal way to do it.

Comment: Shortly, I need to block an operation triggered via REST till the previous operation finishes. It is event processing pattern that can not be dealt with in parallel. This Semaphor works just fine. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

Testing multithreaded code can be quite messy. My preferred approach is to use ManualResetEvents to control the execution order. This usually require that you have some way to instrument the code to test, by injecting the test code or some other way.

So something like this should give a consistent test result:

```
    SemaphoreSlim MySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public ManualResetEventSlim BusinessLogicReached= new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    public ManualResetEventSlim BusinessLogicWaiting = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    public bool InitializeUpdate()
    {
        // This instruction lets routine quit if lock is taken by other thread
        if (!MySemaphore.Wait(0))
        {
            // if can not enter the lock
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            BusinessLogicReached.Set();
            BusinessLogicWaiting.Wait();
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            MySemaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        var updateTask = Task.Run(InitializeUpdate);
        BusinessLogicReached.Wait();
        Assert.IsFalse(InitializeUpdate()); // Semaphore taken
        BusinessLogicWaiting.Set();
        updateTask.Wait();
        Assert.IsTrue(updateTask.Result);
        Assert.IsTrue(InitializeUpdate()); // Semaphore released
    }
```

That said, these kinds of tests are cumbersome to write and maintain, and does not prove general thread-safety, so it might be more cost effective to do thorough code reviews of multi-threaded code.